# exiftool prevent duplicate iptc:keywords/xmp-dc:subject when using add +=

Tags: batch-file, xmp, exiftool, iptc

**problem:**

When i have a jpg whith iptc:keywords=holliday and i execute

- exiftool myImage.jpg -IPTC:Keywords+=holliday -IPTC:Keywords+=ocean

the image has two "holliday" tags

to avoid duplicates i currently use

- exiftool myImage.jpg -IPTC:Keywords-=holliday -IPTC:Keywords+=holliday -IPTC:Keywords-=ocean -IPTC:Keywords+=ocean

so "-=" has no effect if the keyword does not exist in the jpg yet.

however this method has the disadvantage that the jpg is always modified even if it is not necessary because the keyword is already there.

is there a more efficient axiftool-api call way to add a keyword/subject that only changes if it is neccessary?

**background:**

currently i am implementing meta-data sync for keywords/subjects between android and pc.

android generates a msdos batch script entry for every change made and i use an exiftool based bat 
script to apply the metadata changes on the pc side

since the pc Keyword changes can come from different android devices Keywords must be added/removed and cannot be completely set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exiftool.exe myImage.jpg -if "not $keywords =~ \"holliday\""  -IPTC:Keywords+=holliday
```

If the keyword is not present, add it.

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
exiftool.exe ^
    -if "not $keywords =~ \"holliday\""  -IPTC:Keywords+=holliday ^
    -execute ^
    -if "not $keywords =~ \"ocean\""  -IPTC:Keywords+=ocean ^
    -common_args myImage.jpg
```

Comment: Does this syntax also work if i have more than one keyword in one exif api call? Example: I already have *holiday* and i want to make shure that afterwad *holliday* and *ocean* are set?

Comment: This approach does have multiple weakness you should be aware of.  First, it will fail if the word you're looking for is a substring of an already existing keyword.  For example, if you want to add "ocean" and "pacific ocean" or "oceanfront" is already there, "ocean" will not get added.  The `$keywords =~` is a regular expression and if your keyword contains any special characters `[\^$.|?*+()`, then you will get unexpected results.  Finally, this command will read each file once for each keyword.  Adding 5 keywords, that's 5 passes.  Adding a lot of keywords might be a performance hit.

Comment: @MC ND, you can use single quotes instead of escaping double quotes e.g. `-if "not $keywords =~ 'holliday'"`

Comment: @StarGeek, You are right, just quick and dirty solution. Files are parsed multiple times, but I didn't saw another way to deal with it calling only once the executable (at least in windows exiftool process creation is slow) without writing code. But we are here to help and to learn, so, if you know a better/faster/safer/ way of dealing with it, please, post another answer.

Comment: For a safe and stable long term sync solution, the OPs original command would be best and is the suggested solution in [Exiftool FAQ 17](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q17).    To make the IF command more robust, I would add the sep option and do something like this:  `-sep "##" -if "not $keywords==~/(^|##)(ocean)($|##)/"`  This will prevent substring matches.  The other weaknesses still stand and just need to be kept in mind.

Comment: Ooops, typo and can't edit anymore.  `$keywords=~` not `$keywords==~`

Comment: This solution now works for the last 18 months. Last synching akkumulated changes from android to pc for about 20 000 photos took 6 hours but that doesn-t bother me. In near future i plan to replace exiftool-bat script with a java native app that can also handle usecase-file-rename that should use an exiftool-compatible-csv file format with extra non-exiftool-colums for file-rename and file-delete

Answer (score 1):

Some researches on **Linux** bash:

```
exiftool -if 'not $keywords =~ /holiday/' -Keywords+=holiday myImage.jpg ;
exiftool -if 'not $keywords =~ /ocean/' -Keywords+=ocean myImage.jpg ;
```

Double quote is not working here, so here is a way to handle single quotes:

```
exiftool -if 'not $Keywords =~ /harry'\''s/' -Keywords+='harry'\''s' myImage.jpg ;
```

If your regexp has to be case insensitive:

```
exiftool -if 'not $Keywords =~ /joe/i' -Keywords+='Joe' myImage.jpg ;
```