# Adding multiple keywords with Exiftool, but only if they're not already present

Tags: linux, windows, macos, exiftool

I'm running the following command to add multiple keywords to an image:

```
exiftool  -keywords+="Flowering"  -keywords+="In Flower"  -keywords+="Primula vulgaris"  -overwrite_original "/pictures/Some Folder/P4130073.JPG"
```

However, I've noticed that if I do this for an image which already contains a particular keyword, then it'll get added a second time.

How can I ensure that keywords are added only if they're already missing, and that if they exist, it'll do a no-op (and ideally leave the file untouched). I've read a few questions on the forum and the docs, but NoDups docs isn't clear to me (I'm an exiftool n00b) and all the answers I've found only process a single keyword addition.

For an added bonus, if the 'exists' check could be case-insensitive, so much the better (e.g., so that if I'm doing `keywords+="Flowering"` and the image already has the keyword "flowering", nothing will be done.

I also need this to work on Linux, MacOS and Windows (I know the quotes can complicate things!).

Comment: Is this something you are planning to run often and on hundreds/thousands of files?

Comment: Do you have Perl or Python installed on all your platforms?

Comment: Yes, it's going to be run on thousands of systems. And perl may be available, but I just want to use exifTool natively as I'm spawning it as a child process, so want to keep things simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Exiftool FAQ #17](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q17)

> To prevent duplication when adding new items, specific items can be
> deleted then added back again in the same command. For example, the
> following command adds the keywords "one" and "two", ensuring that
> they are not duplicated if they already existed in the keywords of an
> image:
>
> `exiftool -keywords-=one -keywords+=one -keywords-=two -keywords+=two DIR`

The [`NoDups` helper function](https://exiftool.org//exiftool_pod.html#Helper-functions) is used to remove duplicates when they already exist in the file.  It isn't used to prevent duplicates from being added in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen that, but based on a forum post about it, I'm worried about this bit: "To prevent duplication when adding new items, specific items can be deleted then added back again in the same command." - if my understanding is correct, removing and adding won't result in a no-op, but the file will always get touched (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365424/exiftool-prevent-duplicate-iptckeywords-xmp-dcsubject-when-using-add). Is that correct? That said I found this which seems to explicitly describe your solution: https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=10116.0

Comment: Actually, for the process I'm running, it's fine for the file to be touched even if the duplicate tag means it's a no-op, because other dependencies rely on the date/time of the file changing to know it's been successfully processed. So I'll mark this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: It's not something I've checked to see if the file is touched or not, but the [`-P` (`-preserve`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#P--preserve) (uppercase P, lowercase is a different option) will preserve the system timestamps.

Comment: Myself, I'm lazy.  I don't worry about duplicate keywords until I'm done with the folder.  Then I just run the `NoDups` to clean up the mess as the last step.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this is an automated background process which will run on half a million photos (it's part of my app here: http://github.com/webreaper/damselfly), so I want to try not to add dupe keywords inadvertently, because the cleanup will be a nightmare. ;)